# Restriction of the Galois group for some abelian extension to some subfield

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Assume that $M$ is a finite abelian extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, such that $M\subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$ is the smallest cyclotomic field which contains the $M$ via the Kronecker-Weber theorem.

Is the restriction of the Galois group $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)/\mathbb{Q})$ to subfield $M$ simply the Galois group $Gal(M/\mathbb{Q})$?

Comment: Yes, this is true in any tower of Galois extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a tower of normal extensions of $\mathbb Q$:
$$ \mathbb Q \subset M \subset \mathbb Q(\zeta_m).$$

In this situation, we have a surjective group homomorphism:
$$ \phi : Gal(\mathbb Q(\zeta_m) : \mathbb Q) \to Gal(M : \mathbb Q),$$
which sends each $\sigma \in Gal(\mathbb Q(\zeta_m) : \mathbb Q)$ to its restriction $\sigma|_M \in Gal(M : \mathbb Q)$.

[Since $M : \mathbb Q$ is a **normal** extension, we have $\sigma(M) = M $, so this definition makes sense. And since $\mathbb Q(\zeta_m) : \mathbb Q$ is a normal extension, every $\mathbb Q$-automorphism of $M$ extends to a $\mathbb Q$-automorphism of $\mathbb Q(\zeta_m)$, which means that $\phi$ is surjective.]

Anyway, the kernel of the group homomorphism $\phi$ is $Gal(\mathbb Q(\zeta_m) : M)$. Hence $\phi$ induces a group isomorphism:
$$ \frac{Gal(\mathbb Q(\zeta_m) : \mathbb Q)}{Gal(\mathbb Q(\zeta_m) : M)} \cong Gal(M : \mathbb Q),$$
which is the isomorphism you are looking for.

$$ $$